# Magento 2.2 Web Setup Wizard missing

Tags: module, setup, magento2.2

I am running Magento 2.2 and the Web Setup Wizard is missing.  When I use the url: admin/admin/backendapp/redirect/app/etc on the backend.  It leads me to /setup/index.php/session/unlogin not /setup/#/home.  So I have no way to use the component to install 3rd party extension.  Please help!!

Comment: Hi, where you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: If there is http:// then the setup Wizard will show up. but not for https://.

Comment: It should be admin/admin/backendapp/redirect/app/setup not etc.

Comment: Somehow the https:// also works now!!